# Knowing if gps has detected fixes

Tags: android

I want to know if the gps is active and able to report fixes. (basically the gps icon is solid and not blinking). I checked other answers on SO but I was wondering why this answer wouldve work (or would it). Basically every second I request location and if the timestamp of the current location is equal to the last one then there is no fix. Otherwise the timestamp will keep increasing right?

Comments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right way to do it is to request gps status updates, and implement the onStatusChanged function.  The status GPS_EVENT_FIRST_FIX will be passed as soon as you have enough sattelites to calculate the location.

Comment: I have seen this in other posts, but what about my suggested solution. Why would it be wrong

Comment: Three reasons.  First, it won't work if the screen goes off unless you use an alarm.  Second, if you use an alarm you'll eat battery.  Third, its inefficient-  your thread would be woken up every second even if there are no changes, taking processor power from other apps and eating battery.

Comment: Battery for me is not a issue as the product is intended on always connected phone. I need the app to wake up every second anyways to write to a file. So my question is, does the method that I proposed work or not?

Comment: If the location provider updates the timestamp, then yes it will work.  Not all of them update all fields of the location object though-  for example on my phone GPS doesn't update the speed variables.  The only way to know if it does is to test it.

Comment: Ahh ok. Now that makes sense